# Apple Tree Sapling Struggling

Tags: urban-gardening

I'm in the process of growing the little apple tree you see here from a seed that had germinated within an apple I was eating. I thought it would be interesting to see if it would grow and over the past two years it has seemingly done quite well. It recently came out of dormancy and sprouted an entirely new arm.

However, now the leaves on the new arm are turning brown from the edges in and slowing falling off. I don't understand why it seems to be struggling, it gets regular water (not too much), has lots of direct sunlight, and is fertilized with a 6-2-4 mixture designed for fruit trees.

[image][image][image]

The odd thing is that the other two limbs seem to be doing fine, with little to no browning or drying out.

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Does the container have drainage holes?

Comment: It does, it comes with one of the pots that raises the bottom of the soil out of the water so it fully drains into the integrated pan.

Comment: Maybe it's time to repot with fresh potting soil -- maybe go up a size of pot.  Are you hoping to eventually get some fruit?

Comment: I actually just repotted it about a month ago. At this point I'm just trying to grow a healthy little sapling before worrying too much about trying to ever get any fruit from it.

Comment: Update - Our little friend seems to be doing worse. All the leaves on that stalk are browning and falling off and the other leaves seem to be affected too. I don't hold out much hope atm. Anyone have any suggestions?